# How to remove item from iterable object?

Tags: python, iterable

So lets say I have a class Movies that is iterable and self.movies is a list of Movie objects. How can I create remove_movie method? Method I provided doesn't work because iterable isn't list?

```
class Movies:
    def __init__(self):
        self.movies = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.movies)

    def add_movie(self, movie):
        pass

    def remove_movie(self, id):
        for movie in self:
            if movie.id == id:
               self.remove(movie)
```

Comment: `self.movies.remove`? But beware changing a list's length while iterating over it.

Comment: Surely you have access to the underlying list: self.movies.remove(movie); return

Comment: jonrsharpe, quamrana yes you are right, i totaly overlooked it. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an AttributeError.

```
self.movies.remove(movie)
```

Comment: that is correct, but is there a way to actualy do it on self without accessing atribute? like some dunder method for iterables, or it is how it should be done?